# Debian 9 (VM) After update GUI applications won't start

Tags: debian, virtualbox

I'm running a Debian 9 system in VirtualBox (for development) and updated the system (`apt update` & `apt upgrade`). I got the VM provided and it probably hadn't been updated for a while.

Anyway, after the update I had to reinstall VirtualBox Guest Additions, and I managed to do that.

But after the reboot no applications will start. Under i3 I couldn't do anything because not even the default terminal would open. Under Xfce I at least got uxterm, but no GUI application starts. If I start anything in the terminal like `firefox`, there is no error message, nothing, but the application doesn't start.  I am able to use command line tools like `ls`, `nano` or `htop`. But no GUI applications it seems, not even Xfce Terminal.

I *can* start IntelliJ via `sh bin/idea.sh`

zsh arrow turns red when I try to start sth from terminal, so it seems to actually return some kind of error, but nothing is shown on the terminal

Keepass2, Libreofffice, GIMP start, Atom Editor doesn't.

Any ideas?

Comment: I have a vm on my desktop that when that happens I know I have DNS issues. Any logs?

Comment: Hello @RuiFRibeiro I'm not sure I'm following, how would a DNS issue prevent applications starting? What logs are you refering to? From virtualbox? The terminal itself (UXTerm, XFCE Terminal isn't starting either) doesn't show anything.

Comment: Coincidentally, I have also not yet got to the botton why it happens in that particular case... Got several projects in my hands atm. I have not got to the point of being able to affirm whether it is the cause or a related symptom. But I have recovered in a couple of times making sure DNS/outside communications were (res)estabilished.

Comment: Have you tried any X11-aware command-line tools, such as `xhost` or `xlsfonts`?  Which terminal does `i3` attempt to start?

Comment: i3 tries to starf xfce-terminal for which just nothing happens. xlsfonts and xhost both work @JigglyNaga

Comment: XFCE and firefox are both written with GTK, whereas IntelliJ uses a Java GUI library, and uxterm uses the basic X toolkit.  Are you able to try other non-GTK apps?

Comment: @roaima I think what I have there should be enough,will (re)check it anyway, thanks.

Comment: @JigglyNaga Keepass2, Libreofffice, GIMP start, Atom Editor doesn't.

Comment: GIMP definitely uses GTK, so it could be version-specific.  Can you try building and running a GTK test app, with both 2.0 and 3.0?  https://developer.gnome.org/gtk-tutorial/stable/c39.html

Comment: Yeah, couldn't really find a commonality between the programs that worked or that that didn't work. I'll look into the test app, but probably won't find time today. Thank you!